# Error with composer install Facebook Ads SDK PHP

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to install Facbeook Ads API following the tutorial here: [Facebook Ads API SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk) but when I run composer I get the following error:

```
composer update --lock
```

Result:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: facebook/php-ads-sdk[2.8.1, dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: facebook/php-ads-sdk[2.8.2, dev-master].
    - Installation request for facebook/php-ads-sdk dev-master -> satisfiable by facebook/php-ads-sdk[dev-master].
    - Installation request for facebook/php-ads-sdk 2.8.* -> satisfiable by facebook/php-ads-sdk[2.8.1, 2.8.2].
```

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "facebook/php-ads-sdk",
    "description": "PHP SDK for Facebook ads",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "Facebook Platform",
    "keywords": [
      "facebook",
      "ads",
      "sdk"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://developers.facebook.com/",
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.6",
        "symfony/finder": "~2.6"
    },
    "require": {
        "facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.8.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "FacebookAds\\": "src/FacebookAds/"
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to run:

```
php composer.phar install --no-dev
```

Result:

```
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

I am searching and I can not find the solution :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
php composer.phar update facebook/php-ads-sdk
```

If have errors

Try with

```
composer install
```

instead of

```
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: Run: `php composer.phar update facebook/php-ads-sdk`

Result: `Could not open input file: composer.phar`

Comment: Run `composer install`

Result: `Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update`